# Setting up slots or multiple environments for Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework, devops, azure-bot-service

I am working on developing a Microsoft Bot using Azure Bot Service, in that want to set up different environments or slots for QA, Dev, Staging like how we do in azure app services.

In settings I did not find Deployment Slots option but under settings each setting have Slot Setting check box, is that means can we configure slots in Azure Bot Service as well or do I have to create multiple Bot Service resources each one for each environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to create separate bots, for each environment (i.e. one for Dev and one for Production).

The process to configure and work with a staging deployment looks generally like this:

1. Create two bot apps in your subscription, one for the
   production code and one for staging.
2. Create a deployment source, if you don't already have one. This
   example uses GitHub.
3. For your production function app, complete the above steps in Set up
   continuous deployment and set the deployment branch to the master
   branch of your GitHub repo.
4. Choose deployment branch
5. Repeat this step for the staging function app, but choose the
   staging branch instead in your GitHub repo. If your deployment
   source doesn't support branching, use a different folder.
6. Make updates to your code in the staging branch or folder, then
   verify that those changes are reflected in the staging deployment.
7. After testing, merge changes from the staging branch into the master
   branch. This will trigger deployment to the production function app.
   If your deployment source doesn't support branches, overwrite the
   files in the production folder with the files from the staging
   folder.

Comment: This is the best solution for now, but basically slots will be better.
with slots, you can switch versions immediately once something goes wrong.
Here you would need actually 3 bots to be safe once you've deployed your bot.